# Roles/permissions needed to process cube from a SQL Server Data source

Tags: sql-server, ssas, user-permissions, user-roles

We need to process a cube in SSAS.

The datasource used to generate the cube is an SQL Server standard tabular database.

The user which connects to the database has a sys_admin role with all permissions, but we need to downgrade these permissions for security reasons.

The question is which roles/permissions are needed for the sql user in order to connect to datasource to process the cube (without reaching sys_admin level) ?

Tried db_owner role, without success.

Comment: If SSAS is simply retrieving data and not applying any updates, it might only need *db_datareader* access on the target dataabse.